Rotation of local masterKey in mongoDb keyVault
My application is using a local masterkey to decrypt my datas in mongodb server.. I am planning to rotate my keyfile once a year like manually triggering a separate API to do it.
So using the below code im trying to create a new local masterkey file and re-encrypt the DEK in my keyVault collection. I tried in both java-8 and Node.js (Using Mongosh-2.3.1).. But both fails with the same error. Not sure if my below implementation is correct..
Refered their sample from here
Using mongodb-driver-sync-5.0.0 and mongodb-crypt-1.8.0
kmsProviders.put("local", newlyCreatedMasterKey);

ClientEncryptionSettings clientEncryptionSettings = ClientEncryptionSettings.builder()
                .keyVaultMongoClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                        .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
                        .build())
                .keyVaultNamespace(keyVaultDb+"."+keyVaultColl)
                .kmsProviders(kmsProviders)
                .build();

MongoCollection<Document> keyVault = mongoClient.getDatabase(keyVaultDb).getCollection(keyVaultColl);
for (Document dataKeyDoc : keyVault.find()) {
    Binary id = dataKeyDoc.get("_id", Binary.class);
    BsonBinary dataKeyId = new BsonBinary(id.getType(), id.getData());

    clientEncryption.rewrapManyDataKey(
        Filters.eq("_id", dataKeyId),
        new RewrapManyDataKeyOptions()
            .provider("local")
            .masterKey(new BsonDocument("key", new BsonBinary(newlyCreatedMasterKey)))
    );
}

Using Node.js (Mongosh-2.3.1)
// Creating a new key
const key = require("crypto").randomBytes(96);
fs.writeFileSync('keyfile.txt', key);

// Connection options
var autoEncryptionOpts = {
   "keyVaultNamespace" : "encryption.__keyvault",
   "kmsProviders" : {
     "local" : {
       "key" : BinData(0, key.toString("base64"))
     }
   }
 }

// Created the encrypted client
const client = new Mongo(uri, autoEncryptionOpts);
const keyVault = client.getKeyVault();
const result = keyVault.rewrapManyDataKey({}, {
  provider: 'local',
  masterKey: {
    keyMaterial: BinData(0, key.toString("base64"))
  }
})

Both way returns the same error as below
Error rewrapping data keys: Unexpected field: 'key'

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Exception in encryption library: Unexpected field: 'key'
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.Crypt.wrapInMongoException(Crypt.java:375)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.Crypt.rewrapManyDataKey(Crypt.java:260)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientEncryptionImpl.rewrapManyDataKey(ClientEncryptionImpl.java:173)
        at RotateMasterKey.reEncryptDataKeys(RotateMasterKey.java:122)
        at RotateMasterKey.main(RotateMasterKey.java:56)
Caused by: com.mongodb.crypt.capi.MongoCryptException: Unexpected field: 'key'
        at com.mongodb.crypt.capi.MongoCryptContextImpl.throwExceptionFromStatus(MongoCryptContextImpl.java:156)
        at com.mongodb.crypt.capi.MongoCryptImpl.configure(MongoCryptImpl.java:376)
        at com.mongodb.crypt.capi.MongoCryptImpl.createRewrapManyDatakeyContext(MongoCryptImpl.java:311)
        at com.mongodb.client.internal.Crypt.rewrapManyDataKey(Crypt.java:251)
        ... 3 more

